# Replace structure occurence with my type

Tags: c

Not sure if the title is suggestive enough but here's what I'm trying to do.

Let's say I have some code that I won't touch, basically let's say a function that fills in a structure.

Now that structure is defined somewhere else and I found it easy not to drag the whole thing into the project and just copying the struct definition would be an overkill.

So I defined a new struct with only the relevant fields and I'm trying to send it to the function so that it would be filled up with the relevant fields.

```
typedef struct {
 ......
} mytype;
```

The function header:

```
int function_header (struct type1 *p, ....);
```

Keep in mind struct type1 is not defined anywhere.
Is there a way to abuse the preprocessor to get something like?

```
#define (struct type1) mytype
```

One solution would be I guess

```
#define type1 mytype
#define struct
int function_header (struct type1 *p, ....) {    
#undef struct

..............
}
```

But seems a bit retarded

Comment: "I defined a new struct with only the relevant fields"  Are you trying to treat this struct as if it was the other struct?  If so, that will not work.

Comment: The issue is not what happens in the function. The issue is replacing struct type1 with mytype.

Answer (score 3):

Why do you want to rename it? Just define

```
struct type1 {
    ...
};
```

in your own source file, and you're all set to go a-footshooting. (And remember, feet *will* be hurt unless you're 100% sure that your own definition leads to *exactly* the same in-memory layout as the one expected by the library).

Comment: Won't work. I can't touch the function header, and I can't touch the struct definition. I'm trying to meld them together, it's messed up but this is what I need. I'm 110% sure about what happens in the function :)

Comment: @celleritas - You don't need to _touch_ the `struct` definition, you just ought to _use_ it.

Comment: Who says you need to touch the function header? You place your own definition in _your_ `.c` file, before or after you include the header. Your code will then use it while the function itself uses _its_ definition. As long as the compiler doesn't see both definitions at once, it will compile along happily and leave you to deal with the results.

Comment: Yeah but I already have mytype which is what I have to use. Adding other structures is not an option. That's why I needed to get struct type1 replaced with mytype. This is what I'm asking for, nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: `struct type1 { mytype content; };`

Comment: @Henning Makholm that would assume that the function knows to address fields as type1_data->content.field1 which it doesn't it does type1_data->field1.

Comment: What? The library knows nothing about your local definition in the code you're calling it from. It will use whatever definition was in effect when it was _compiled_, and it's up to you to ensure, in whichever way you find convenient, that you supply it with some memory that matches its expectations.

Comment: @Henning Makholm keep in mind struct type1 is not defined and I am not planning on doing so, that's why I need some precompilation magic to replace all occurrences of "struct type1" with "mytype"

Answer (score 1):

First of all, be careful.  You cannot arbitrarily remove fields from the original `struct` and expect the function to "fill them in".  You can define a compatible `struct` of your own making, but it must contain the *exact* same fields in the *exact* same order, or very bad things can happen.  You can then send an instance of this structure with uninitialized field values to the function, and it will set values into your fields as it normally would.  But you cannot *remove* a field and then expect the function to add it back.

Of course, even if you define an exact copy of the `struct`, you're risking all sorts of issues, as if someone changes the other `struct` without updating your version, things will break.  Similarly things will break if your declaration is updated without a corresponding update made to the original `struct`.  It would be far better to just move the definition of the original `struct` to a shared header file that can be included in all the places that need to use that `struct`.  Then there's just one definition that everyone uses.

But anyways, as your function is just expecting a pointer to the structure, you can call it with pretty much anything you want.  Just cast your parameter to `void*`, as shown here:

http://ideone.com/c4qtT

Of course, as noted above, this will only work correctly if the pointer that you are casting is pointing to something that has an in-memory layout *exactly identical* to the original `struct`.

Comment: Don't worry about what happens in the function, that is being taken care of. Nop I **have** to use exactly what's written there struct type1 and mytype. So no struct mytype.

Comment: Yes, so do like in the ideone example.  Forget about the `#define` tricks, and just cast your `mytype*` to `void*` in the call to your function.  Your function takes a pointer as a parameter.  And a pointer is a pointer is a pointer.  They don't have types.

Comment: @aroth: That's extremely untrue.  Pointers do have types; different types of pointers are not necessarily compatible, and may even be of different sizes.  There happen to be some special-case guarantees, such as that any object pointer can be converted to void* and back without loss of information (which means your idea could work), char* and void* have the same representation, and all struct pointers have the same representation.

Comment: Sorry, I must disagree.  At its most fundamental level, a pointer is just an integer that represents a location in memory.  Size of the variable used to store this number is irrelevant, and should be consistent for every pointer on a given CPU architecture besides.  The only possible exception is if you are casting a 64-bit pointer into a 32-bit (or smaller) type [for the sake of saving some space](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/smallptr.aspx).  But doing that is pretty silly to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

You can define your new structure having the original structure as its first member. Example:

```
struct mytype {
    struct type1 original;
    int custom_field;
};
```

Since the ISO says there will be no padding before the first member of a `struct`, if you have a `struct mytype*`, it allows you to cast it to `struct type1*` without undefined behavior.

However, you'll get into trouble if the original code uses `sizeof` to traverse an array of `struct type1` instances, whereas the original array is in fact of `struct mytype` instances.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do that. The external function doesn't "know" about any defines, redefines, redeclarations, etc. If you make your struct smaller, there is a chance that the function, thinking it is writing to the original struct, writes across the boundaries of your smaller struct.

***Don't do this***, unless you really really really know what you are doing.

Comment: Yes I know, but I'm not worried about what happens in that function, it'll be ok, trust me :)

Comment: I'm worried about YOUR memory being overwritten. If you declare a struct that is smaller, your memory (e.g. your other stack variables or even your function return address) might be overwritten by the function --> kaboom!

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood you don't want to change the header file, but you have full access to the source file?

You wrote:

```
#define type1 mytype
#define struct
int function_header (struct type1 *p, ....) {    
#undef struct

..............
}
```

it seems you can easily modify the function body. Why don't you just manually change all the struct type1 references to mytype? It's just a simple find&replace in text editor...
The thing that preprocessor would do is just the same, it replaces all the occurrences of one text with another.